# Best approach for using mutationObservers on elements which get destroyed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mutation-observers

I'm trying to run a script on an Angular 1 site, my script looks for changes in the DOM to run a function. However since it's a single page app, my preferred mutation target node can be destroyed and replaced which stops the mutationObserver from working as its target no longer exists.
I feel like targeting one of the parent nodes is a bit messy as it will be picking up hundreds of mutations and looking for my preferred one.

Are there any better approaches I could use?

Comment: You can attach `MutationObserver` when replaced element is created and appended to `document`.

Comment: Using this approach you'd have a whole bunch of obsolete mutation observers though right? Would you need to clean out the old ones too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only a single `MutationObserver` instance should need to be created. Before element is removed from `document` call `observer.disconnect()`.

When new element is appended to `document` call `.observe()` method of original `MutationObserver` instance with target element and original configuration.

```js
const el = "div";

let i = 0;

let n = 0;

function create() {

  let div = document.createElement(el);
  div.textContent = el + " " + ++i;
  div.contentEditable = true;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  return div
}

let div = create();

function handleMutation(mutation) {
  console.log(mutation.type);
  if (++n === 3) {
    n = 0;
    observer.disconnect();
    div.parentElement.removeChild(div);
    div = create();
    // use same `MutationObserver` instance for new `<div>` element
    observer.observe(div, config);
  };
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(handleMutation);
});

const config = {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  characterData: true
};

observer.observe(div, config);
```

Comment: Ok thanks good to know it can work like that. I am still having trouble because I don't have control over the elements getting removed or added, that's all done by the angular app. Aside from watching a parent element, let me know if you have any other ideas. In the meantime I'll mark thsi answer as it's within the scope of my original question.